# Can't resolve local packages with SwiftPM

Tags: swift-package-manager

I am using Xcode 13.2.1 and ran into a following problem. When importing any of local package to root project files (in my case it is AppCoordinator) a compiler shows an error

> Cannot find type 'DashboardFlow' in scope

DashboardFlow is the name of the local package. In order to solve a problem I do:

- Clean DerivedData folder
- Resolve all local packages one by one
- Open Xcode and resolve package graph once again

The result is just the same compiler error.

Please tell me what might help in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to manually add your `DashboardFlow` library to your target.

- open your project in Xcode.
- click the target you want `DashboardFlow` to be imported and used.
- click `general`.
- find `Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Contents` section.
- click `➕` button, find `DashboardFlow`, then add it.

You will be able to use `DashboardFlow` in **THIS** target.